# Angularjs ng-repeat start a new row for each 4th item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a list of apples, and I want to place 4 apples in each basket. in HTML, it will look like this:

```
<div class="basket">
   <span class="apple">Green</span>
   <span class="apple">Green</span>
   <span class="apple">Green</span>
   <span class="apple">Green</span>
</div>

<div class="basket">
   <span class="apple">Green</span>
   <span class="apple">Green</span>
   <span class="apple">Green</span>
   <span class="apple">Green</span>
</div>
```

I want to be able to do this using ng-repeat in Angualrjs:

```
<div class="basket" ng-repeat="apple in apples>
   <span class="apple">{{apple.color}}</span>
</div>
```

for every 4 apples create a new basket etc.

Comment: So, the way I see it, this is either a model problem or a visual problem. If it's a visual problem, it might be best to do something with css or even use a framework to ease that like Pankaj suggested. If it's not a visual problem, it looks like you should have basket items which contain a collection of apples. You'd ngRepeat the baskets, then inside the basket, ngRepeat that basket's apple collection.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried, ng-if

```
 <div ng-repeat="apple in apples" ng-if='$index % 4 == 0' class='basket'>
         <span class="apple"> {{apples[$index].color}}</span>
         <span class="apple"> {{apples[$index +1 ].color}}</span>
         <span class="apple"> {{apples[$index + 2].color}}</span>
         <span class="apple"> {{apples[$index + 3].color}}</span>
  </div>
```

[See the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Q9heSmRUqmkhlvp70bm?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best answer lies in how you structure your model.  I would fill it in a hierarchical manner that would best support the desired rendering in html.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.appleBaskets = [{
    basketId: 1,
    apples: [{
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      color: 'gold'
    }, {
      color: 'red'
    }, ]
  }, {
    basketId: 2,
    apples: [{
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      color: 'yellow'
    }]
  }, {
    basketId: 3,
    apples: [{
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      color: 'red'
    }]
  }]
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="appleBasket in appleBaskets">
    <div>{{appleBasket.basketId}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="apple in appleBasket.apples">
      <span>{{apple.color}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have an array of `basket`s that each contain an array of `apple`s. Then you could nest `ng-repeat`s as so...

```
<div class="basket" ng-repeat="basket in baskets">
   <span class="apple" ng-repeat="apple in basket.apples">{{apple.color}}</span>
</div>
```

If you only want to have a one dimensional array of apples rather than a 2 dimensional array of baskets containing apples then you could make the apples visually group into fours with CSS.

One way to do this would be to set up a CSS class called `new-line` for example and define this to set `display: block;` or whatever you want to use to force a new line.

Then use `ng-class` to set the CSS dynamically based on the `$index` value.

```
<div class="basket" ng-repeat="apple in apples" ng-class="{ 'new-line' : $index % 4 === 0 }">
   <span class="apple">{{apple.color}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know the width of class `basket`, then you can set the with of class `apple` to be 25% of the total width:

```
.basket {
    width: 500px;
}
.apple {
    width: 125px;
}
```

Comment: Don't ya just hate it when people downvote but don't leave a comment?  It's like they're afraid of discussing their reasoning.